# Добавить связь к промежуточной таблице

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Возникла проблема с добавлением роли к аккаунту.

Есть три таблицы : `auth_accaunt` `auth_accaunt_role` `auth_role`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связь между ними `Many to many`. При добавлении роли в коллекцию, связь между аккантом и ролью в промежуточную таблицу не добавляется. Сам аккаунт создается, но не устанавливается связь с ролями для него. Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо выполнить.

Часть кода из контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUserAccount(
        @ModelAttribute("accaunt") Accaunt accaunt, 
        @ModelAttribute("role") String roleStr
    ){
        Role role = roleDAO.getId(Integer.valueOf(roleStr));
            Set<Role> roles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            roles.add(role);
        accaunt.getRoles().add(role);

        accauntDAO.save(accaunt);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Сущность accaunt:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_accaunt")
public class Accaunt implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "auth_accaunt_role", 
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_accaunt")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")
        }
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    private User user;

    public Accaunt() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Сущность ROLE

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_role")
public class Role implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Role() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка из-за моей невнимательности... Оказалось дело вообще не в маппинге...

Было:

```
@Override
    public Role getId(Integer id) {
        Role role = null;
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.get(Role.class, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        return role;
    }
```

Стало:

```
@Override
    public Role getId(Integer id) {
        Role role;
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            role = session.get(Role.class, id);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        return role;
    }
```